# Como referenciar um jar de outro projeto no Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, ireport

Estou fazendo um projeto para testar relatórios do iReport, e queria saber se tem como não incluir os mesmos jars que já existem em um determinado projeto. O próprio Eclipse oferece a opção de referenciar as classes deste outro projeto, o problema que ele mostra o caminho como por exemplo `c:\eclipse\projeto`. E isso me preocupa pois vou compartilhar o projeto no SVN, e será que se outro desenvolvedor ao baixar não irá causar erro de direcionamento do jar?

Gostaria então de saber como fazer o direcionamento dos jars, e se isso vai causar o problema acima mencionado.

Comment: Sugiro um gerenciador de dependências para solucionar seu problema, o Maven. Veja [**aqui**](http://luizricardo.org/2014/06/instalando-configurando-e-usando-o-maven-para-gerenciar-suas-dependencias-e-seus-projetos-java/) todas suas vantagens, como instalar e coisas do tipo.

Comment: @Math por agora fica complicado inserir um gerenciador de dependências como o `Maven`.

Comment: Bom, você pode então passar junto com seu projeto todos as dependencias que você usa e pedir para o outro desenvolvedor incluir no projeto dele. Pois acredito sim que dará o problema que voce citou devido ao caminho real, e não o relativo.

Comment: Ou aguarde por uma resposta de alguém que tenha uma ideia melhor :)

Comment: @Math sua ideia é boa também, estou pesquisando algo relacionado a variavel de classpath no Eclipse. Obrigado

Answer (score 1):

O iReport (pelo menos nas versões que conheço) não consegue usar variáveis do Eclipse.

Entretanto, você pode adotar um padrão em sua equipe usando variáveis de ambiente. Cada desenvolvedor deve ser responsável por criar e configurar corretamente o seu ambiente.

Então ele deve apontar essa variável, por exemplo, para a raiz do projeto. Isso permitirá que um desenvolvedor possa ter vários workspaces ou mesmo diferentes *branches* de um projeto.

O problema é que para testar um determinado projeto ele deve garantir que aquela variável de ambiente realmente aponta para aquele projeto. Isso pode causar confusão em alguns casos.

Outras alternativas são:

- Em ambientes linux, você pode configurar um link simbólico para a pasta de jars e usar esse caminho no iReport. Por exemplo, crie em cada máquina um link em `/etc/projeto1` que aponte para a pasta de jars. E coloque o caminho desse link no iReport.
- No Windows, você pode usar o comando `subst` para configurar uma unidade virtual com os jars. Por exemplo, use `subs P: c:\workspace\projeto1\lib`. Então o padrão será que os relatórios desse projeto apontem sempre para a unidade `P:`. Outras unidades podem ser usadas para diferentes projetos.

Comment: Cara, só para informar, eu tenho 2 projetos. Um é a aplicação em si, e ela contem  os `jars` e o outro seria o projeto de teste que eu gostaria de testar os relatórios criados fora do sistema. Uma especie de `TDD` do `Ireport`.

Comment: @Macario1983 Você está usando JUnit ou algum método `main`? Em qualquer um dos casos, adicionar o outro projeto no `classpath` pelo Eclipse deveria ser suficiente.

Comment: Utilizo método `Main`